# ArangoDB Single Instance as a Docker Container Fills memory and restarts

Tags: docker, arangodb, arangojs

We are running ArangoDB `v3.5.2`. The Docker container unexpectedly restarts at random intervals, and all the connected clients get disconnected. After further investigation, we found that Docker container running Arango is reaching the memory allocated to it fully. The memory gets filled incrementally ever since the container starts running and it never goes down, until it is filled and the container restarts.

Below is the docker command used to run the container

```
docker run -d --name test -v /mnt/test:/var/lib/arangodb3 --restart always --memory="1200m" --cpus="1.5" -p 8529:8529 --log-driver="awslogs" --log-opt awslogs-region="eu-west-1" --log-opt awslogs-group="/docker/test" -e ARANGO_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=1 -e ARANGO_STORAGE_ENGINE=rocksdb arangodb/arangodb:3.5.2 --log.level queries=warn --log.level performance=warn --rocksdb.block-cache-size 256MiB --rocksdb.enforce-block-cache-size-limit true --rocksdb.total-write-buffer-size 256MiB --cache.size 256MiB
```

Why does the memory keep increasing and does not go down, especially when it is not being used? how do i solve this issue?

### My Environment

- **ArangoDB Version**:  3.5.2
- **Storage Engine**: RocksDB
- **Deployment Mode**:  Single Server
- **Deployment Strategy**: Manual Start in Docker
- **Configuration**:
- **Infrastructure**: AWS t3a.small Machine
- **Operating System**: Ubuntu 16.04
- **Total RAM in your machine**: 2GB. However, the container's limit is 1.2GB
- **Disks in use**: SSD
- **Used Package**:  Docker

Answer (score 0):

There's a known issue if you have mixed settings with comments in the configuration file arangodb.conf (source: https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/5414)

And here's the part where they talk about the solution: https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/5414#issuecomment-498287668

> I think the syntax config file syntax does not support lines such as
>
> block-cache-size = 268435456 # 256M
>
> I think effectively this will be interpreted as something like
>
> block-cache-size = 268435456256000000, which is way higher than intended.

just remove the comments, and retry!